# MPLAB X sample project for Ethernet connection running on PIC32MZ

Tags: ssl, ethernet, pic32

I have downloaded and installed the MPLAB X IDE v2.05 and the latest Harmony v0.8.
However I don't find any sample project that would demo an Ethernet connection using the PIC32MZ EC starter kit ? 
My goal is to try an SSL connection, but I'd like to start somewhere above scratch.

Any hint ?
Kind regards,
Jean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just gone through Microchip forum (http://www.microchip.com/forums/m798425.aspx). The following open source TCP/IP stack seems to support PIC32MX/MZ and some SSL-based projects are available for the PIC32MZ EC Starter Kit (SSL client and secured SMTP client). Refer to the demo/pic32mz_ec_starter_kit/ directory from: http://www.oryx-embedded.com/download/CycloneTCP_CycloneSSL_CycloneCrypto_Open_1_4_4.zip

Hope it will help.